# Spring getEnvironment()

Tags: spring

Hi i am trying to write down a simple example of using Spring Profiles her is the code .

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
 GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(); 
 ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("kindergarten"); 
 ctx.load("classpath:profile/*-config.xml"); 
 ctx.refresh(); 
 FoodProviderService foodProviderService =     
     ctx.getBean("foodProviderService", FoodProviderService.class); 
 List<Food> lunchSet = foodProviderService.provideLunchSet(); 
 for (Food food: lunchSet) { 
     System.out.println("Food: " + food.getName()); 
 }
```

} 
But strange thing happens it  GenericXmlApplicationContext dose not have getEnviroment() method in it's API so the third line

```
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("kindergarten");
```

dose not work.My STS refuses to run the main because he think this is a sintax error he gives me this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method getEnvironment() is undefined for the type GenericXmlApplicationContext
```

any ideas ?
 thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer it seems i had 3.0.6.RELEASE Spring version but Profiles where added from 3.1.0 version so all i needed to do is go to my pom.xml and change this.

```
    <spring.framework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
```

To this

```
        <spring.framework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
```